# Extract a list of all active employees (records) as at a particular date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and  have a table called tbEmployees. An extract of this table is shown below:

```
 empID     HiredDate      LeftDate
  108      2014-05-11     2016-04-20
  109      2015-05-14     2015-12-28
  ...
```

How can I get a list of all active employees as at '2018-07-01'? In other terms, I want to extract all employees who were active in the company as at that particular date.

I have tried this syntax but I am not sure it is extracting the right information:

```
 SELECT * FROM tblEmployee
 WHERE HiredDate <= '2018-07-01' and LeftDate >= '2018-07-01'
```

Comment: Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Is `LeftDate` `null` prior to a staff member leaving?

Comment: Is it always during a single date, or could it be a date span?

Comment: @DaleBurrellYes, it is NULL for those who are still active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With BETWEEN:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee
WHERE 
  ('2018-07-01' BETWEEN HiredDate AND LeftDate)
  OR
  ('2018-07-01' >= HiredDate AND LeftDate IS NULL)
```

The condition `LeftDate IS NULL` just in case the employee is still active.

Answer (score 1):

What you had seems fine to me, other than it may not consider employees that are still active (i.e. has no value for LeftDate). You may need to include an `OR` condition to capture this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblEmployee
WHERE HiredDate <= '2018-07-01' 
AND (LeftDate >= '2018-07-01' OR LeftDate IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little tweak to your solution, to include those still hired.

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-07-01'

SELECT *
FROM tblEmployee
WHERE HiredDate <= @Date
 AND (LeftDate >= @Date OR LeftDate IS NULL)
```

If you want all that were hired during all of a timespan instead of a single date:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-07-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2018-07-02'

SELECT *
FROM tblEmployee
WHERE HiredDate <= @EndDate
 AND (LeftDate >= @StartDate OR LeftDate IS NULL)
```

Or those that were hired at any portion of the date span:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-07-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2018-07-02'

SELECT *
FROM tblEmployee
WHERE HiredDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 OR LeftDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 OR (HiredDate <= @EndDate AND LeftDate IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE HiredDate <= '2018-07-01' and LeftDate >= '2018-07-01'
```

Your above statement will suppose to work as it will automatically convert the string '2018-07-01' into the DateTime format for a date of 2018-07-01 00:00:00.

Or maybe can can also try

```
     SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE HiredDate <= '01/07/2018' and LeftDate >= '01/07/2018'
```